# Исключения, throw/throws

Tags: java

```
class NestTry {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
            int a = args.length;
            int b - 42 / a;
            System.out.println("a=a" + a);
            try{
                if (a == 1) a = a / (a - a);
                if (a == 2) {
                    int c[] = {1};
                    c[42] = 99;
                }
            } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Индекс за пределами массива: " + e);
            }
        } catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("Деление на нуль: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**ВОПРОС 1:**
Что значит в коде

```
if (a == 1) a = a / (a - a)?
if (a == 2)?
```

Для чего прописывается `a = a / (a - a)?
Каким образом a относится к`с`, ведь`с` это массив?

```
int c[] = {1};
c[42] = 99;
```

**ВОПРОС 2:**
чем отличается `throw` от `throws`?

**ВОПРОС 3:**
для чего мы прописываем в данном коде повторно 
`throw new IllegalAccessException("демонстрация");`?

```
class ThrowsDemo{
    static void throwOne() throws IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(" В теле метода throwOne(al).");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("демонстрация");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]{
        try{
            throwOne();
        } catch(IllegalAccessException e) {
            System.out.pritln("Перехвачено исключение: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Для чего прописывается a=a/(a-a)?

очевидно, чтобы намеренно сгенерировать исключение при делении на ноль. Учитывая, что а имеет тип int, вычитание а-а будет иметь в результате ноль, что и приведет к исключительной ситуации при делении.

> чем отличается throw от throws?

throw выбрасывает исключение, а throws говорит о том, что метод, к которому это относится, может выбросить такое исключение, не обработав его внутри. То есть throws сам ничего не выбрасывает, а только сигнализирует об этом, заставляя разработчика соответствующим образом обрабатывать этот метод

> для чего мы прописываем в данном коде повторно throw new IllegalAccessException("демонстрация")

здесь нет повторного выброса исключения. Есть throws, который сообщает о том, что метод **может выбросить** это исключение и throw new IllegalAccessException("демонстрация"), который его **выбрасывает**

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, throw - обрабатывает и выбрасывает исключение, а throws предупреждает о том, что может быть такое исключение, исключение не обрабатывает, выбрасывает его.

Comment: нет, неправильно. throw выбрасывает исключение, но не обрабатывает его. Для обработки есть блок catch конструкции try-catch-finally. throws не выбрасывает исключение, а только объявляет о   том, что метод может его выбросить

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно!!!!

Comment: @Ya16 коль все понятно, поддержите автора, ответив ответ как правильное решение, нажмав на зеленую галочку

Comment: Подскажите, если я хочу просто предупредить о том, что метод может выбросить прописываем                                                                                        class ThrowsDemo{
    static void throwOne() throws IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(" В теле метода throwOne(al).");

Comment: Если необходмо выбросить. прописываем                                                                                       static void throwOne() throws IllegalAccessException {
        System.out.println(" В теле метода throwOne(al).");
        throw new IllegalAccessException("демонстрация");
    }